# Error while applying threshold on my image using opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0, python-tesseract

As i'm doing card scanning to extract the text from images i want to get exact text from image but i'm getting only accurate image values from card and im trying to applpy adaptive threshold on my card but i'm geeting error like

```
 File "C:/Users/shruthipriyanka/PycharmProjects/Scanning/sample.py", line 11, in <module>
    newimage = cv2.resize(oriimage,(583,327))
Type Error: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

can anyone explain what i did wrong and suggest some resolution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What most likely is happening is you are passing the resize function a PIL image. You can do something like this`pix = numpy.array(pic)` to convert the image to a numpy array.